# Dynamically pickup the correct OS and processor architecture using CGO

Tags: go, cgo

I have access only to a linux and darwin distributions of dynamically linked shared libraries.

Following is how I've integrated the library with Golang

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/build -lprocessing_lib
// #include "Processing-bridge.h"
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

type ProcessorWrapper struct {
    ptr unsafe.Pointer
}

func init() {
    pr.ptr = C.NewProcessor()
}

func GetDefault() (id int, name string) {
    var default = C.GetDefault(pr.ptr)
    id = int(default.materialId)
    name = C.GoString(default.name)
    return
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I copy the matching library under the build/ folder.

I'm trying to make this as a go gettable library , where it could work on both linux and darwing architectures.

Problem I'm having is to tell go compiler to pick the right library for the matching GOOS and GOARCH.

I tried having a folder structure like below

```
build/darwing/libprocessing_lib.so
build/linux/libprocessing_lib.so
```

And modified the LDFLAGS as below

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/build/${GOOS} -lprocessing_lib
```

However it doesn't recognise ${GOOS} and replace it with the correct value.

Is there a way to achieve this dynamic library pickup feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an easy way to achive this without creating multiple files by looking at the go source code it self [cgo](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f595848e9a1e1d0f64a7018d847167d85f6e83a4/src/runtime/cgo/cgo.go)

```
// #cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/build/darwin -lprocessing_lib
// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/build/linux -lprocessing_lib
```

we can also pass the Architecture if needed like below

```
// #cgo darwin,arm64 LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/build/darwin -lprocessing_lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you have:

`library_darwin.go`

`library_linux.go`

And in each file, have the correct `#cgo`flags (but the same code)?

Depending on the target OS, go will build only the correct file (see [here](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/))